# Excel UserForm.Print

Tags: excel, vba

Good Morning. I am having trouble with a segment of code that has worked well in the past for me.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

UserForm1.Show

End Sub
```

Stored in the UserForm

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'   Verify All Fields
Msg = "Have you entered all Fields?"
Title = "TONU"
Config = vbYesNo + vbQuestion
Ans = MsgBox(Msg, Config, Title)
    If Ans = Yes Then GoTo nextstep:
    If Ans = No Then Exit Sub

nextstep:

'   Print Option
Msg1 = "Would you like to Print a hard copy?"
Title1 = "TONU"
Config1 = vbYesNo + vbQuestion
Ans1 = MsgBox(Msg1, Config1, Title1)
    If Ans1 = Yes Then UserForm1.Print
    If Ans1 = No Then Run Report


lastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

MsgBox lastRow


End Sub
```

The UserForm prints fine in my other project, but when a use this code in a new project it does not print?!?!  Thoughts?

Comment: Could you post the rest of your code?

Comment: Is UserForm1 indeed the right object?

Comment: OK, This is all i have written thus far.

Comment: K_B, the (Name) property is UserForm1 and the Caption is TONU

Comment: The correct method to print a form is `.PrintForm` instead of `.Print`

Comment: CaBieberach, I have tried both .Print & .PrintForm...

Comment: Do you get any error message? or it just goes by the print method without reacting? have you scroll through your code with F8?

Comment: CaB, It doest not debug or eror out.  It just bypasses like its not there...

Comment: use `vbYes` and `vbNo` instead of Yes and No

Comment: Cab, that was the answer!!! vbYes and vbNo in the "If Ans" section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Yes" is not a valid `VbMsgBoxResult`.  It should be `vbYes` or `vbNo`.  In the first instance your code will just fall through to `NextStep`.  In the second it will do nothing.

To avoid this type of error use `Option Explicit` at the top of your modules.  Then it will complain that Yes and No are undeclared variables.

Better yet, check "Require Variable Declaration" in Tools>Options, to have Option Explicit automatically placed at the top of each module.